# User Login to Web Page with VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am trying to login to a web page using `VBS`, however despite of passing correct credentials I am getting "Incorrect Credentials" errors in the Login Page. This is my script

```
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.visible=1
IE.navigate "http://192.168.83.131/LMS/Index.aspx"

Do While (IE.Busy)
WScript.Sleep 10
Loop    
Set CompanyName = IE.document.getElementByID("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_ddlOrganization")
CompanyName.selectedIndex = 1   
Set UserID = IE.document.getElementByID("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_txtLoginId")
UserID.Value = 1010737

Set UserPass = IE.document.getElementByID("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_txtpassword")
UserPass.Value = "Welcome@123"    
Set UserSubmit = IE.document.getElementByID("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_btnLogin")
UserSubmit.click    
set IE =Nothing
Set CompanyName=Nothing
set UserID=Nothing
Set UserPass=Nothing
Set UserSubmit=Nothing
```

When I manually login using the same credentials its working fine. In order to check which parameter is set incorrect by the `VBS` (Login ID or Password), I removed `UserSubmit.click` and tried removing the first the `Password` and passing it manually and then removing the `UserID` and passing it manually, both the instances I get `Incorrect Credentails`.

Not able to make out what is causing the Problem, this is an Intranet Page which I am trying to automate using `VBS\VBA`

EDIT:
Attached is the background javascript events

```
<select name="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1$ddlOrganization" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'WUC_LoginWithDomainId1$ddlOrganization\',\'\')', 0)" id="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_ddlOrganization" style="width:90%;">
        <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1,No">(Corporate)</option>

    </select>

<input name="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1$txtLoginId" type="text" id="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_txtLoginId" class="input" onkeypress="return EnableKeys(14);" style="width:87%;">

<input name="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1$txtpassword" type="password" id="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_txtpassword" class="input" style="width:87%;">

<input type="submit" name="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1$btnLogin" value="Log In" onclick="return ValidateForDomain();" id="WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_btnLogin" class="Button">
```

Comment: Sounds like the common denominator is the `<select>` control. Have you tried setting `CompanyName.value = ` to the _value_ of the `<option>` element you are trying to select? Or maybe even `CompanyName.options(CompanyName.selectedIndex).selected = True`.

Comment: I have already tried both the options, it didn't work. Also, as mentioned earlier, if I run the `vbs` disabling the `UserSubmit` and keyin the `userid` and `password` manually (removing the one set by the `vbs` code) it works (without changing the `company name`)

Comment: Ah, okay. You actually _didn't_ mention the second part. You just said it works "manually" when you enter the credentials (which I assumed meant not using a script at all). Have you checked to see what kind of JavaScript runs on the page? Maybe there's some crazy `onkeypress` validation logic or something.

Comment: Sorry for that  I have changed the question to add the `Java-scripts` details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took sometime for me to solve this. The best possible solution I have found is to use the [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/) `COM Add in`

```
Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  Call driver.Start("chrome", "http://192.168.83.131/LMS/Index.aspx")
driver.Open "http://192.168.83.131/LMS/Index.aspx"

driver.findElementById("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_ddlOrganization").AsSelect.selectByText "(Corporate)"
driver.findElementById("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_txtLoginId").SendKeys "1010737"
driver.findElementById("WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_txtpassword").SendKeys "password"

   driver.Click "WUC_LoginWithDomainId1_btnLogin"
```

Hope someone will find this useful.